# Can I use /deep/ with Angular 7, will it not be a problem in a future update?

Tags: angular

In my Angular 7.2.0 component I am using a https://www.devexpress.com/ component. I am not able to override the CSS with the component's CSS file unless I use the `/deep/` flag. For example:

```
/deep/ .dx-editor-cell .dx-texteditor .dx-texteditor-input {
    background: blue;
}
```

Is this correct approach? If I update to Angular 8 will there be a problem? Or is there any other correct way to do it?

Comment: Although listed as deprecated (https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#deep--and-ng-deep-component-style-selectors) there is no scheduled removal or suggested replacement.

Comment: I am still using ::ng-deep, even though that one is deprecated as well. If you are going to use any of the deprecated ones, ::ng-deep is preferred.  `>The shadow-dom-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such, in v4 we deprecated support in Angular for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep. Until removal, ::ng-deep is preferred for broader compatibility with the tools.`

Comment: Like with the MatDialog from Angular Material Design, you can specify a cssPanelClass, and some other third party components have an @Input()-decorator, which can be used to add a container class for styling. Does the component you use from devexpress have that? If yes, that is the recommended approach In my opinion.

Comment: **Avoid** use ::ng-deep. Why not use ViewEncapsulation.None? well it's necesary enclosed your component under a div to avoid the .css affeted all your appplication but it's more natural